# NodeJS: Bcrypt: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt, bcryptjs

This is part of my code from the controller I am using to do validations for the login app, so everything is being inserted correctly into the database and its encrypted right, but the moment I try to submit user data it fails to validate the password, says the errors it's at the bcrypt. compare, I put the right one and even if I put the wrong it should redirect me to Home, instead the program crashes.

```
Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
    at _async (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main (1)\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:286:46)
    at C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main (1)\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:307:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.bcrypt.compare (C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main (1)\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:306:20)
    at C:\Users\CHINO\Desktop\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main (1)\Sistema-Pre-Escolar-Manitas-De-Oro-main\controllers\authController.js:31:6
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

**AuthController.js :**

```
exports.PostLogin = (req, res, next) => {

    const password = req.body.password
    const email = req.body.email

    User.findOne({ where: {email : email}})
    .then((user) => {
        if (!user) {
           flash.req("errors","Ha ocurrido un error al momento de ingresar el Correo electronico")
    return res.redirect("/login")
    }

    bcrypt
    .compare(password, user.password)
    .then((result) =>{
        if (result){
            req.session.IsloggedIn=true
            req.session.user = user
            return req.session.save((err) =>
            {
                flash.req("errors","Contreseña invalida")

                console.log("Error al momento de compare",err)
                res.redirect("/")
            });
        }
        res.redirect("/login")

    });
```

Comment: `req.body.password` seems to be`undefined`. Can you verify with your debugger?

Comment: Have you printed `password` and `user.password`  so you know what you got?

Comment: You are treating asynchronous calls like they are synchronous. The look up by email to get the user is not going to be returned before the bcrypt code runs. You either need to use await or you need to put the bcrypt code inside of the user look up then.

Answer (score 0):

as @epascarello mentioned, You are goin through the users collection and trying get a user based on your entered email which should be wraped with Async - await call. This way it awaits for the user is found then goes to compearing the password with `bcrypt`

```
exports.PostLogin = async (req, res, next) => {

    const password = req.body.password
    const email = req.body.email

    await User.findOne({ where: {email : email}})
    .then((user) => {
    bcrypt
    .compare(password, user.password)
    .then((result) =>{
        if (result){
            req.session.IsloggedIn=true
            req.session.user = user
            return req.session.save((err) =>
            {
                flash.req("errors","Contreseña invalida")

                console.log("Error al momento de compare",err)
                res.redirect("/")
            });
        }
        res.redirect("/login")

    });
```